# Two pointers in a class with constructor to another class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor, reference

This is for my term assignment. There are two headers defining classes, tubes and nodes.

This is a fraction of node.cpp:

```
    cie::node::node(int node_id, int node_x, int node_y, int node_flow)
{
    id_ = node_id;
    x_ = node_x;
    y_ = node_y;
    flow_ = node_flow;
}
```

Here is the tube.h:

```
#include <node.hpp>
#include <fstream>


namespace cie
{
    class tube
    {
    public:
        tube();
        tube(node* node_a, node* node_b, double tube_diameter);

        const node* node1() const;
        const node* node2() const;
        double length();
        double permeability();
        double diameter() const;

        void print();

    private:

        node* node1_, node2_;
        double diameter_;

    };
}
```

I'm simply trying to create the **cie::tube::length** fuction with the Pythagoras of x-y differences of node_a and node_b.

**How can I point to these coordinates differently in the tube class section?**

Comment: What does "how can I point to these coordinates differently in the tube class section" mean? Your question is unclear.

Comment: `node_a` and `node_b` are parameters of the constructor. There don't seem to be any `node_a` or `node_b` in the scope of the `length` function. Do you mean `node1_` and `node2_` instead?

Comment: Do you know how to use pointers, and class methods, and how to reference class members from class methods? What, specifically, about pointers, classes and their methods and members, is unclear to you?

Comment: Yes i meant node1_ and node2_